# How to create a share with CloudKit's CKShare?

Tags: ios, swift, share, cloudkit

I'm studying the new `CKShare` that Apple released this year and I have some questions with it. I was trying to follow the WWDC's "What's new in CloudKit" video but part of the code isn't working anymore in Xcode.

What I'm trying to do is: the user will enter his name and phone and after clicking a `UIButton`, will share with a specific person. Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICloudSharingControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var nome: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var telefone: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func send(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Send button was clicked.\n")

        let elder = CKRecord(recordType: "Elder")
        elder["name"] = self.name.text as CKRecordValue?
        elder["telephone"] = self.telephone.text as CKRecordValue?

        let ckContainer = CKContainer.default()
        let shareRecord = CKShare(rootRecord: elder)

        shareRecord[CKShareTitleKey] = "Elder" as CKRecordValue?

        let shareController = UICloudSharingController(share: shareRecord, container: ckContainer)
        shareController.delegate = self
        shareController.availablePermissions = [.allowReadOnly]
        shareController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.button

        self.present(shareController, animated: true)
    }

    func cloudSharingController(_ csc: UICloudSharingController, failedToSaveShareWithError error: Error) {
        print("PROBLEM SAVING SHARE")
    }

    func cloudSharingControllerDidSaveShare(_ csc: UICloudSharingController) {
        print("SHARE SAVED")
    }

    func itemTitle(for csc: UICloudSharingController) -> String? {
        return "a"   //don't know what this is for
    }
}
```

My app keeps printing "PROBLEM SAVING SHARE" even though the CloudSharingController appears. Also, the CKRecord *elder* isn't appearing in CloudKit's dashboard.

Comment: Update `print("PROBLEM SAVING SHARE")` to `print("PROBLEM SAVING SHARE: \(error)")` so you know why it's failing.

Comment: Yeah, I did right after I posted here... but anyway, the error is: `An added share is being saved without its rootRecord (<CKRecordID: (-big cloudkit stuff-):(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>)`. Basically I'm not creating the root record, but I don't understand, the root record is `elder` and it's right above it!

Comment: Should I save the record before trying to create a share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I figured out what was wrong... I was using the default zone that cloud kit creates for you and you CANNOT do that when using CKShare.
All you have to do is create a private custom CKZone and save the CKRecord and CKShare in it!

Comment: The default zone doesn't support sharing a custom zone does.

Comment: Yes, for sharing, the item (CKRecord) must be stored in a custom private zone. But this is not the only problem in your case. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60683437/3143890

Answer (score 0):

I was told that you can use the initializer that you have chosen to use only if the share has already been created. For new shares, use the alternate init

Try this code:

```
let csc = UICloudSharingController { controller,
        preparationCompletionHandler in
        let share = CKShare(rootRecord: elder)

        let mro = CKModifyRecordsOperation(
            recordsToSave: [elder, share],
            recordIDsToDelete: nil)


        mro.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = {
            records, recordIDs, error in
            if error != nil {
                    //handle error
            }
            preparationCompletionHandler(share,CKContainer.default(), error)
        }
        myDB.add(mro)
    }

    csc.delegate = self
    self.present(csc, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Hey! I tried your code but I'm getting an error in `mro.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock`. I printed the error and only say this: `Optional("Failed to modify some records")` and, I think, because of that I'm not being able to create a share cause right after that I get the "PROBLEM SAVING SHARE" message error...

Comment: I also created a closure to make sure that the record is first created to then call the CKShare methods but not even this seems to work...

Comment: The CloudSharingController appears without problem but this error happens when I click any button to share, for example, "Copy link".