# Cannot share CloudKit CKShare record

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to implement cloud kit sharing in my application, however, whenever I try to share an item using a `UICloudSharingController` I'm getting a consistent error:

I am presented with the initial share popover for adding people, and then when I select one of the options on how I'd like to send the invitation (i.e: by mail), the `UICloudSharingControllerDelegate` returns calling:

```
func cloudSharingController(_ csc: UICloudSharingController, failedToSaveShareWithError error: Error)
```

And throws the error:

**CKError 0x170245d60: "Invalid Arguments" (12); "An added share is being saved without its rootRecord (CKRecordID: 0x1700343e0; recordName=C9FA0E96-3461-4C9E-AB99-3B342A37A07A, zoneID=PrivateDatabase:__defaultOwner_)"**

I've already created a custom zone in the private cloud database for the user whose zoneId is "PrivateDatabase". I've created an object and successfully saved it to iCloud and it is linked to the custom zone I previously created. The code I am using to present the UICloudSharingController is as follows:

```
let object = // A core data representation of a CKRecord //

let share = CKShare(rootRecord: object.record) //record is a CKRecord that is stored with the core data object 
share[CKShareTitleKey] = object.name as? CKRecordValue
share[CKShareThumbnailImageDataKey] = UIImagePNGRepresentation(object.categoryKey.icon()) as? CKRecordValue
share[CKShareTypeKey] = "reverse.domain" as CKRecordValue
share.publicPermission = .readOnly

let sharingController = UICloudSharingController(share: share, container: self.container)
sharingController.delegate = self
sharingController.availablePermissions = [.allowPrivate, .allowReadOnly]
sharingController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
controller.present(sharingController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong initializer for an instance of UICloudSharingController.
There are **two different initializers** for **two different use cases**.

- If an item is shared the first time (not already shared) you have to create a new instance of CKShare with a rootRecord (as you did in your code) but then you have to initialize your UICloudSharingController with this Initializer `init(preparationHandler:)`
- If an item is already in a sharing process, then you have to fetch the existing share from iCloud and initialize your UICloudSharingController with this Initializer `init(share:container:)`

So, the error in your case is, that you create a new instance of CKShare but then use the wrong initializer.

[more from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller)

Comment: How do you know if an item has already been shared or not?

Answer (score 0):

did you check in iCloud, whether the share has the correct link to the root record in the correct zone etc., and/or the rootRecord is existing...

Comment: just checked the WWDC2016, thats what I meant: "..You always need to create a Share with a root record so there's always something in the Share.

Next, we're going to save that Share and the root record to the server at the same time.

You want to do that because there's a new property on CKRecord that's a reference to the Share that we're creating.

By saving the root record and the Share at the same time, that reference will be set to the share you just created......"

Comment: I've checked and I've created the share with the rootRecord that was provided to me from CloudKit. This issue still persists.