# Using CKCloud kit to share private records

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cloudkit

I am using the following code to attempt to create a shared private record:

```
@IBAction func testPress(_ sender: Any) {

    let customZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "ShareZone")
    let friendRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Share", zoneID: customZone.zoneID)
    let rootRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Root", zoneID: customZone.zoneID)

    model.privateDB.delete(withRecordZoneID: customZone.zoneID) { (nil, error) in
        self.model.privateDB.save(customZone) { (nil, error) in
            print("Custom Zone Error = \(error)")
            self.model.privateDB.save(friendRecord, completionHandler: { (nil, error) in
                self.model.privateDB.save(rootRecord, completionHandler: { (nil, error) in
                    self.shareTest(record: friendRecord, root: rootRecord)
                })
            })
        }
    }
}

func shareTest(record:CKRecord, root:CKRecord) {

    record["Name"] = "Test" as CKRecordValue?
    root["Name"] = "Test" as CKRecordValue?

    let ckContainer = CKContainer.default()
    let shareRecord = CKShare(rootRecord: root, share: record.recordID)

    shareRecord[CKShareTitleKey] = "Name" as CKRecordValue?

    let shareController = UICloudSharingController(share: shareRecord, container: ckContainer)
    shareController.delegate = self
    shareController.availablePermissions = [.allowReadOnly]

    self.present(shareController, animated: false)
}
```

However I am returning the error when I press on a way to share the link:

> CKError 0x6000002535f0: "Invalid Arguments" (12); "An added share is being saved without its rootRecord (CKRecordID: 0x608000224560; recordName=C0ADC819-57F7-4D99-A527-B21590F506AB, zoneID=ShareZone:**defaultOwner**)"

I looked at this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514231/how-to-create-a-share-with-cloudkits-ckshare) who was having the same problem, but do not quite know how to get their solution to work as they didn't provide enough details.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the error message is telling you need to save the share and root record at the same time.

```
let modifyRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation( recordsToSave: [record, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
```

You should do this operation in the completion handler of the sharingController.

```
sharingController = UICloudSharingController {
                        controller, preparationCompletionHandler in
```

Edit: Your code would look something like this not tested code:

```
@IBAction func testPress(_ sender: Any) {
    let privatedatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    let newZoneName = UUID().uuidString
    let recordZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "ShareZone")

    privatedatabase.save(recordZone) {  savedRecordZone, error in

        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription).")
        } else if let savedRecordZone = savedRecordZone {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription).")

            let rootRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "RootRecord", zoneID: savedRecordZone.zoneID)
            rootRecord["Name"] = "Test" as CKRecordValue?

            privatedatabase.save(rootRecord) { record, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription).")
                } else if let record = record {
                    print("successfully added rootRecord to cloud.")
                    self.shareTest( rootRecord: record)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func shareTest(rootRecord:CKRecord) {

    let ckContainer = CKContainer.default()
    let shareRecord = CKShare(rootRecord: rootRecord)

    let sharingController =  UICloudSharingController { controller, preparationCompletionHandler in

        let share = CKShare(rootRecord: record)
        share[CKShareTitleKey] = "Share Title" as CKRecordValue
        share.publicPermission = .none

        let modifyRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation( recordsToSave: [rootRecord, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
        modifyRecordsOperation.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        modifyRecordsOperation.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10

        modifyRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, recordIDs, error in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            if let records = records {
                print("Share and Root records saved successfully")
            }
            preparationCompletionHandler(share, CKContainer(identifier: ckContainerID ), error)
        }

        myCloudDatabase.add(modifyRecordsOperation)
    }
    if let sharingController = sharingController {
        sharingController.availablePermissions = [.allowReadOnly, .allowReadWrite, .allowPrivate]
        sharingController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        sharingController.delegate = self
        self.present(sharingController, animated: true)
    }
}

// MARK: UICloudSharingControllerDelegate
// --------------------------------------
func cloudSharingController(_ csc: UICloudSharingController, failedToSaveShareWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to share to cloud: \(error)")
}
func itemTitle(for csc: UICloudSharingController) -> String? {
    return "Please join rootRecord share."
}
func cloudSharingControllerDidStopSharing(_ csc: UICloudSharingController) {
    print("Cloudkit stopped sharing")
}
func cloudSharingControllerDidSaveShare(_ csc: UICloudSharingController) {
    print("Cloudkit started sharing rootRecord")
}
```

Comment: this looks great, how would I implement it - could you modify my code?

Comment: required a few modifications but did the job!!   Thanks